# How i can fixed the dataGridView Column index

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset, datagridviewcolumn

iam used datagridview and i have some Columns without  DataPropertyName
if me load data To DataGrid 
the Index of Columns is changed
 you can try in my Sample attach

click on button "Change Currnt Cell By Index "  To move in datagrid cell

the index of Column changed after click the button "Load Data"

how i can fixed the index ?

attachFile

 https://app.box.com/s/4dezi14hy84z8mumxtsqymn7718dr6bh

Comment: What (and how) does the Load button do? After adding columns to the fron etc tthe index will change. You can instead simply use the column names, though.

Comment: you should try to improve the question adding the affected code. by the way, the image link doesn't works.

Comment: Where it will be difficult if i use names because I make it a general rule for all Forms

Comment: The link is not image but a link compressed source code file